# Building my Flat Earth, how to make my Ice walls last for eternity

Tags: earth-like, water, alternate-earth, ice, nonspherical-worlds

In a world where

1. Earth does NOT have gravity (Gravity does not exist).
2. Our oceans are created by Ice walls.
3. Ice walls? How can they exist so long?

In the Flat Earth model, the Ice walls are situated OUTSIDE of the planet, which means that Solar winds, UV rays, etc. could be battering it every moment. Thus negating the statement that the Ice walls surround the planet. Is there any "possible" scientific way to have this kind of Ice wall?

**Characteristics**

1. Situated on the outer rim of the planet, so that Earth's ocean does not dry up, or fall into space.
2. The Ice walls shall not melt for all eternity.

Ice walls last forever! But please help me to explain this tommorrow.

EDIT:

It seems to look like most of the people here think I'm a flat earther. (It's actually funny to see the comments and answers). I was only wondering on how to make the Ice wall on a flat earth remain for all eternity, without gravity affecting it, or is it even possible?)

P.S. Magellan's crew circumnavigated Earth in 1522 *wink*

*This is important since everybody thinks I'm a flat earther, here is a proof that the earth was circumnavigated*

[image]

Comment: As there is not scientific basis for anything like a flat earth, any explanation will do. I´d go with: The Elephants, carrying your Earth-disc through space, fart magical freezing gases. *Edit: The Point I am trying to illustrate here is, there is no way to get a scientifically conclusive explanation for your flat earth. You can use more, and more complicated words, like in @Cort Ammon´s answer an maybe fool some of your readers for some time or you could cut straight to the point: This doesn´t work for real, dont think about it too much!*

Comment: Since the Flat Earth could never form naturally, the simplest explanation is that whatever magical force/god created it wanted it that way. The walls have some kind of regenerating/cooling effect built into them to protect the disc.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83971/discussion-on-question-by-mr-j-building-my-flat-earth-how-to-make-my-ice-walls).

Comment: @Renan almost missed that due to your typo on my name. Try the autocompletion? :) Anyway, the 'answer' doesn't really attempt answering the question seriously. Instead it's a criticism disguised as an answer. And before you say that the question is not seriously answerable, check the one below by Cort Ammon. It takes the actual issue in the question, and then tries to solve ot using examples of real world things and science.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T there is no autocomplete in mobile :(

Comment: "there is not scientific basis for anything like a flat earth"? Wrong there is the pie-plate construct used as a stepping stone in the creation of Larry Niven's Ringworld; it's a flat disc with the surface area of a planet and 1000 mile high mountains the whole way around the edge to keep the atmosphere in, accelerated at a constant 1G for pseudo-gravity. You can read all about it in _[Bigger Than Worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigger_Than_Worlds)_

Comment: But what is the lifespan of a world turtle, what happens to the elephants when it dies?

Comment: @Separatrix See I always assumed, don't ask me why, that the turtle would outlive the disc, elephants and all.

Comment: Does the ice wall need to be made of traditional ice? As in, can it be something resembling ice that is not really frozen water?

Comment: @Ash, there are 4 elephants though (or 5), that leaves the option for making more elephants, but only one turtle.

Comment: @Separatrix Possibly, but how would they go about making little elephants without tilting the world? Also you're forgetting about the Big Bang Theory explored in _Science of the Discworld_ which postulates that there many world turtles, a theory of which Nanny Ogg would thoroughly approve, and they get together to swap stories and make more turtles once in a while. Maybe they could swap elephants around, or even discs, while they were all together.

Comment: @Ash: If you accelerate constantly at 1G (how, why? where does the energy come from?), you will eventually approach relativistic speeds and ultimately exceed the speed of of Light - and you will get in trouble with science again... I remain that is not more realistic than the elephants ...

Comment: @Separtrix We *know* that there are many World Turtles, because we are shown others in "The Light Fantastic".

Comment: @Daniel You're assuming straight-line acceleration.  If you were constantly turning with 1G of acceleration, then you would inscribe a large circle instead.

Comment: @Chronocidal: No and no. How would that result in artificial gravity. If you had a constant change of direction in your acceleration you will have a hard time keeping the sea in its intend place. Is just is not getting any better! (and still, where is the acceleration energy coming from?)

Comment: @Daniel The same way that spinning a bucket keeps the water in - with your ice-walls in place of the bucket.  Essentially, you're generating a standard rotating-ring habitat, but excising 99.9% of the perimeter.  As for "where does the energy come from" - that's for OP to handwave in their own manner - perhaps the disc is tethered to track attached to a Dyson sphere?

Comment: @Chronocidal That would not be called constant acceleration but centrifugal force. You´d need some counter force, like a big ass chain and a fixed point to keep the disc rotating. Does not sound very scientific to me ...

Comment: @Daniel Centrifugal Force is **caused** by acceleration.  Rather than a chain-and-fixed-point, you *could* just stick huge thrusters on the "back" of the planet - like a car drifting in donuts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84042/discussion-between-daniel-and-chronocidal).

Comment: our world is going to be constantly losing ice to space through sublimation, that is actually a major source of lose to glaciers at higher altitude, exposed to vacuum it will be far worse. So your world is going to be constantly losing water mass even with the ice wall.

Comment: What do you mean by the wall is outside of the planet? If it's outside, water will flow away.

Comment: This question should be given more seriousness, even though people ostracize the flat earth thing. If I ask how to make an nuclear bomb that can destroy the universe, or ask how to kill an immortal god etc, I'm not asking how to make it work in the real world, but in my fantasy world with more realism and making people more into the plot. Unless the question species that, which is not the case.

Comment: @Mr.J,  No, gravity is not a component of a wall.  But it is a component of air pressure, which ice depends on, and your refusal to deal with this is a problem.  I personally don't care if your wall is held down by clamps, corkscrews, glue, scotch tape, chewing gum, gravity, or your declaration that it is so. Without an explanation of air pressure both at ground level and at the top of the walls (normally done via gravity), you're encouraging the argument.  As written, I don't forsee the question reopening.

Comment: @JBH If I had known that, I would have included gravity... such a shame I lack the science behind my question( Please, no sarcasm intended, I really though gravity is not a variable on ice to any extent). Its Ok though, I have learned a lot from this question. Let the question be and remain closed.

Comment: @JBH In a disk spinning around the sum, air pressure can be entirely explained by centripetal/centrifugal force. No need for gravity.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Nightsky cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiative_cooling) will be important.

The sky is cold.  Even with a full atmosphere in the way, it can act as though it is -50F.  With no atmosphere, it can get down to almost 0K.  That lets you radiate a lot of heat!

Clearly the only source of heat or UV radiation or whatnot is the sun, which we know orbits closer to the center of the flat earth, so there wont be as much irradiance falling on the ice (see that there?  I used science!)

Thus the ice walls are simply the equilibrium between the cooling capacity of the sky and the heating capacity of the sun and oceans.  And not one alien or pyramid was involved in it's making!

The only issue left is the question of lasting for eternity.  I'm going to chalk it up to a linguistic mismatch when they use the word "eternity," because there no known scientific principle for why any configuration of atoms will remain for eternity.  However, when your life experience is short enough that you can't have walked around the planet enough to observe any curvature, it's reasonable to use "eternity" when you're really just talking about a very long time.  Even [real comets](https://www.thenakedscientists.com/articles/questions/how-long-does-it-take-comets-melt) last 10,000 years.  A large body of ice like the ice wall could last much longer.  That'd be long enough for the dinosaurs to go hide all of the fake fossil evidence for us!

Comment: Should I also indicate that the flat earth is based on round earth's solar system?

Comment: @Mr.J Probably.  It helps to know just *how* much bad physics is involved.  I was relying on the recent flat earth model which at least got the length of the day and night cycle correct through the seasons for various latitudes.

Comment: I thought they believe that the flat earth is in a solar system like ours?

Comment: @Mr.J They are an enormously disjoint bunch.  Everyone is constantly picking their favorite inconsistency in the data and trying to make it work.  Leads to a lot of models.

Comment: This will be my last take on something controversial.. I only want a never ending supply of Ice wall.

Comment: @Mr.J You might also have fun with [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/107053/how-long-lasts-a-second-of-eternity).  It got closed as off-topic, but not before we got some good engineering estimates regarding how long eternity is!

Comment: While this solve the temperature problem (as per the question), how long would it take for the walls to crumble into a slope?

Comment: @Eth That's a great question.  It'd definitely depend on the height of the wall.  And I wonder if there's an approach that lets you shore up this ice wall with a bunch of frost from humidity coming from warmer places.  This answer was based on a related question about what would happen if a rod of absolute 0 existed in our atmosphere.  The result was condensation built up a nice wall.

Comment: @Eth My Idea is when the Ice exceeds flat earth's "Shield?" Atmosphere, the Ice melts due to the Sun's heat. That's me assuming that the flat earth is situated in a Goldilocks location like earth.

Comment: Water will evaporate into the space vacuum even at 0°K. Also Ice kind of flows, look at glaciers...

Comment: @Daniel Yes, entropy does win in the end.  That's the purpose of the last paragraph.  Flowing could be an interesting limitation thouhg.

Comment: @Mr.J It seems that, around here, ANYTHING can be turned into something controversial. It all depends on which side of the 'in' group you are on, and the strength of the underlying mood for looking for something to attack..

Comment: @JustinThyme I thought Flat earth was an idea of the ancient times? You know, the time when exploring near the edge of the earth will make you fall to the edge of the earth? I cited Magellan's travel because its one of the proofs that the world is round, because they basically (accidentally) circumnavigated Earth.

Comment: @Mr.J  Nope, there is absolutely no corroborated ancient text that refers to a 'flat earth'. Any reference to such is only a few hundred years old. Not even the Greeks believed in a flat earth. Atlas held up a globe,. The circumference was pretty much calculated about four THOUSAND years ago, and never ever  through all history or mythology was it ever disputed that the earth was round.. At no time, in any historic record, is there ANY mention of falling off the edge of the earth, except in modern revisionist history.

Comment: Magellan KNEW the earth was round.  He knew astronomy, and used it to navigate, The star charts at the time all accounted for the earth's curvature. See [this, for example](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1982JBAA...92...53H) There were no flat earthers until modern Western mythology created them. If Magellan did not have a concept of the earth as globe, he would never have been able to find his way back home.

Comment: See [Myth of the flat Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myth_of_the_flat_Earth) for further reading. Now ask yourself, 'Why would the educational system deliberately teach a falsehood, as if it were the truth? What advantage is there for training people to believe in falsities? Who best profits from accustoming and conditioning people to believing in untruths, and accept them without question?'

Comment: @JustinThyme, I have read them from a book a looooooong time ago, that the ancient times believed that the world was flat, then was debunked by Aristotle, with further proofs provided by the star maps used by Sailors/Explorers (Magellan, Columbus, etc, etc..)  of which became the proof Earth is round. I cant give you the citation sadly (there's no wiki citation either) What are you actually insisting on may I ask?

Comment: I was taught that in elementary school in the 50's, complete with drawings and pictures of monsters attacking sailing ships. All fake. Even today, many American public schools are still teaching the myth that Columbus set sail to prove the earth was round. All fake. My point is that you can propose a disk-like world, no problem. That is the prerogative of fiction and fantasy writing.  But those who try to link it to a fictitious belief that the general public in the 1400's or before believed in a flat earth, they are as far off reality as the actual positing that the earth is flat.

Answer (score 4):

**If there is no gravity, then there is no earth**

Let's start with that statement - there is no gravity. Does mass then not get attracted to each other? Would there even be a sun? How did this disk form?

A possible way to do this but keep this statement true (but retain scientific 'gravity') is for a far advanced alien civilisation, creates a disk world, and 'constantly accelerates' the disk through space to form 'gravity' (without 'gravity').

Your ice walls perhaps are not really ice walls, but structural integrity members created by the aliens as a network of crystalline carbon nanotubes.

However the aliens will need to push the disk (and the sun and the moon) at 9.8 m/s/s to retain this effect. At this acceleration, your system will quickly within a few years reach very fast speeds and you will notice the stars significantly blue-shifted, and you might notice other strange effects. Needless to say, over centuries no-one may know where your system will end up.

Answer (score 1):

**snow**

Disclaimer: I hope to provide something to help suspension of disbelieve, as there is imho no way something like this could ever survive real scrutiny.

As the center of your world is warmer than the edge, high pressure area's will naturally occur there, creating winds towards the edges. These winds will carry the water vapor that originates from your oceans, and when they reach the colder regions at the edge will release said water vapor in the form of snow. The snow will fall on your walls, get compacted into ice under it's own weight and slowly move downwards to replace the ice that is lost to melting in your oceans. So while the *walls* are eternal, the ice it consists of is actually always moving, being replenished from the top and melting away from the bottom.

If this sound familiar to you it should, because this is (in a nutshell) the mechanism of real world glaciers. Of course it wouldn't *actually* work, what with the physical impossibility of a flat earth and all, but maybe it's something that can be made to sound convincing.

Answer (score 1):

The official flat-earther explanation is that the sun races over what we globists call the equator. It is far from the wall, which gets little to no radiation at all. As for the interstellar medium, it does not exist - it's just yet another lie.

[image: You just lost an IQ point for looking at this.]

The truth is far more complex than that, though. The Earth is not flat - the ice wall is actually a ring around a giant finger. It has ice because the ring is metallic and as we all know, metals are naturally cold.

[image]

The wall will last as long as the ring exists, which might be forever from a civilization's point of view. It will be removed if the giant ever gets a divorce though.

Comment: @Mr.J so you are ok with an answer based on farts being the most upvoted, whilst an answer based on alternative formats and an actual mechanism for heat sinking being downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a closed system or a system where energy that comes in and goes out tends to be balanced.

Now, think of winter and summer. The sun goes around the flat earth, not following a circular motion, but a slight oval shape. Each day getting closer to one side of the glacier and getting further away from the opposite side. Or taking longer to pass through the summer side and going quicker over the winter side. Oversimplifying it, this creates areas where sunlight is stronger and areas where its dimmer.

The wall that is closer to the sun melts and the opposite side builds up ice from the seas, maybe from atmospheric humidity. Basically, the freezing side loses energy to the vast space. Each cycle tends to balance things out and maintain itself immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this flat planet is situated in our solar system then placing it  at the same distance as the planet Mars Would mean that the sun would never warm it enough for water ice to melt.

You would then have the problem that everything inside the ice walls would also be frozen, as you wouldn't have any geothermic activity causing warming (because the planet is flat) but that's not part of the question.

https://www.lpi.usra.edu/education/explore/ice/background/iceSolarSystem/

Comment: Without gravity, how would it orbit anything?

Comment: Good point.  I'll change my answer to "at the distance of Mars from the sun".  Although if gravity doesn't exist then the sun won't exist in the first place.

Comment: Caution, trying to seriously deal with flat-earth logic could harm your brain ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can build this world, according to Larry Niven's [Bigger Than Worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigger_Than_Worlds) at least, you'll need to read the full text of the piece to get what you're looking for, it's the "Pie-Plate" world proposed as an intermediate stage of [Ringworld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringworld) construction. It's a flat disc with the surface area of a planet and a miles high wall around the outer edge to keep the atmosphere in. And some form of infinite fuel rocket under it thrusting at 1G to give the surface pseudo-gravity and keep it in a stable orbit (you can take this off since you don't have gravity).

The problem is with use Ice in particular for that wall, it will tend to [Sublime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublimation_(phase_transition)) rather than melting when heated in a vacuum and the gas will be almost impossible to retain and refreeze. The walls can be made of [something stronger](http://larryniven.wikia.com/wiki/Scrith) and designed to act as radiators leaving them frosty on the inside but presenting a hard ablation resistant face to the radiation and debris of space. Such a wall would form an integral part of the world's water cycle; the water vapour frozen onto them would act like a glacier in terms of a water source for the world.

Note those walls won't last for eternity, nothing does, but they'll largely still be there long after the star they're orbiting burns out, even if they spend some time inside that star in the process. The material suggested for their construction is not currently a real material, in fact it probably qualifies as a form of exotic matter. What you could use that is a real material, although one we cannot yet make it with our current technology, is what Wil McCarthy calls [Wellstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacking_Matter), a programmable lattice that can create pseudo-atoms with properties that can't exist in nature.

Comment: Going with the disk idea and the miles-high wall, you really do not need gravity. If one posited a very long, very strong cable or tether that connected the sun to the center of the disk, and then spun the disk around the sun. centripetal/centrifugal force would flatten everything against the disk. That is, everything would be given a velocity that, through inertia, wanted to continue on a tangent, but the rotation of the disk 'cuts it off', like swinging a pail of water around your head. All the effects required, but no gravity,

Comment: @JustinThyme That's a lot harder to do than strapping a rocket to it.

Comment: Hey, I just picked up my media device and read on the news that a RingWorld was under construction. Or not. Hard? Meh. Never been a limitation before.

Comment: @JustinThyme By "lot harder" I mean "not doable", at least not with the basic technology you need to build the disc.

Comment: I do not recall a 'science-based' or 'reality-check' tag. How 'doable' is RingWorld?

Comment: @JustinThyme That can only be answered as "depends on the scale"; a full size Niven Ring? Maybe not ever, the forces are immense thus the material suggestions in my answer, we don't know of any existing material with the tensile strength. Something a couple of miles across based on the same principle we can build now, materially at least.

Comment: Same with my tether material.

Comment: @JustinThyme Except the tether is harder to build than the disc which is easier to build than a full ring.

Comment: Something about 'the light just keeps going around in a circle and back to the beginning'.

Answer (score 0):

The presence or absence of gravity is a red herring in this scenario. Completely irrelevant. The water would not fall off the disk because of gravity, unless there were some very distant gravitational source pulling it away from the planet, nor would it stay on the disk because of gravity. If gravity DID exist, the water would form into a ball at the center, not flat on the disk surface.

There is another much more important factor.

Centripetal/centrifugal force. If the disk-earth were spinning', the water would be flung off simply because it was given a velocity, and inertia would keep it going in one direction (a tangent to the disk). Thus, the walls would be required to counter this centripetal/centrifugal force. However, what WOULD happen is that the water would bunch up against this wall, and it would then flow over it, unless the ice wall itself had a lip on it. Spin a flat disk around your head with water on it. The water will certainly not remain there. But put the water in a pail? The sides of the pail keep it in.

So, don't spin the planetary disk at all. No centripetal/centrifugal force. No gravity, so the water does not all bunch up into a ball. Nothing pulling the water 'down', so it does not flow off.

OOOps, forgot about surface tension.

Surface tension would tend, just like a drop of water, to keep the water 'bunched up' so it does not slide off. Ever see the pictures from the ISS crew, drinking water, spilling it on a 'desk'? Same idea.

So your ice walls have a very reduced task. Surface tension would keep the water flat against the disk.

The cold of space would keep the walls ice, as log as they were protected from radiation, and sublimation.

So, coat the ice with a thick layer of lipids that form cell membranes. Make one end hydrophobic, one end hydrophilic. They would stay only on the surface of the ice, with the hydrophobic end facing outside and the hydrophilic end bound to the ice. In effect, you are exponentially increasing the surface tension. Since lipids can be very long polymers, the intertwined polymer lipids would form a very strong 'skin' around the ice. This would prevent sublimation.

Since water, and ice, are very good shields against radiation (it has been posited to put huge water tanks around the Martian transport craft to protect the inhabitants), and allow the hydrophobic end of the lipids to form a very reflective coating, and your problem is solved.

No centripetal/centrifugal force to 'spin' the water away, no gravity to cause it to flow 'down' (wherever 'down' is), or to the center, an ice wall protected from sublimation and radiation, kept in place by very long chain polymers, and surface tension keeping it from floating off into space.

Except, well, there is the problem of preventing ALL the water from freezing. But then, if it all froze, problem solved. It would be one huge iceberg covering the planet.

**EDIT**

If you DID allow gravity, your situation is greatly simplified. Spin the disk at such a speed that the gravitational pull causing the water to 'ball up' is perfectly balanced by the centripetal/centrifugal force of the spinning water. As long as the forces balanced, the water would stay on forever (assuming sublimation is taken care of).

Answer (score 0):

What if it's just "ice all the way out"?  If the Earth is flat, then all of the heavens are on one side of the plane of the Earth's surface.  There's no opportunity for us to look for stars or planets on the same plane, and certainly no opportunity to look "behind/below" the Earth.  So -- why do we need for there to be another side of the ice wall?  Maybe it's not a wall at all, but just solid ice extending infinitely in every direction, with our Earth the only break in the ice.

In that case I don't think you have to explain the ice sticking around.  It simply has no place to go.

Comment: An extremely imaginative solution. World of Minecraft comes to mind.